# Cannot select based on condition in attribute selector

Tags: jquery

If I do `$var = $('[height > 100]');`

It is throwing error runtime error

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [height > 100]

But equals(=) works

```
$var = $('[height = 100]');
```

So how can I filter for the first case? (using attribute selector only just because I am learning it)

I have  `<table height="200">`

Thanks

Comment: Please consider changing your display name - with your current default name `@` won't work and you might miss some comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$var = $(target).filter(function() {
  return $(this).height() >= 100;
});
```

Here `target` will be replaced with any valid [**jQuery selectore**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)

#### Note

If you use `height` with `style` css then your way is not possible.

#### According to edit

```
<table height="200">
```

Then try

```
$('table[height=200]');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/54jba/1/)**

**OR**

```
$var = $('table').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr('height') == 100;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AnnGE/4/)**

#### According to commebt

> Q. Does it work for `!=`?
>
> A. YES

```
$var = $('table').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr('height') != 100;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AnnGE/7/)**

Comment: But I want to use attribute selector only (just because i am learning)..is it not possible?

Comment: @user1323981 if you use `height` with `style` css then its not possible

Comment: that means it works only for equal to (=) and not equals(!=) and for no other conditional operators!..right!

Comment: @user1323981 check my answer for `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an attribute selector, just use thecodeparadoxes method like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uVdcw/

```
$var = $("div").filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).attr("height")) >= 300;
}).text("height is 300 or more");​
```

And the HTML:

```
<div height="200" width="100">Div 1</div>
<div height="300" width="140">Div 2</div>
<div height="200" width="130">Div 3</div>
<div height="500" width="120">Div 4</div>
<div height="200" width="120">Div 5</div>​
```